# Python: Find First Redirect of URL

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib2, urllib

In Python, how would I find the URL of only the first redirect

I.e. if a URL redirects from A -> B -> C I want to just return the url B

`urllib` seems to only return the final url but I want to list an intermediary URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are committed to using urllib2 or if that's just the first thing you tried.

if you are open to using requests:

```
import requests
url = 'someurl'
r = requests.get(url)

print("first redirect",r.history[0].url)
print('full history')

for n,h in enumerate(r.history):
    print(n,h.url)
```

you can filter out things that arn't redirects using h.status_code

for example

```
codes_i_want = [301,some_code,some_other_code]
result = [h for h in r.history if h.status_code in codes_i_want]

if(result):
    print(result[0])
```